# Help debugging sql query: where do I have an extra ( or )?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

This query works:

```
SELECT     u.UserId, u.GroupId, u.username,
            gp.PreferenceId, gp.Properties, gp.Override
        FROM          dbo.UserTable u 
        Inner JOIN
            dbo.GroupPreferences gp ON gp.GroupID = u.GroupId
        WHERE      (u.UserName = 'myUserId')
```

But the same query inside another query doesn't. I get the errors "Invalid column name 'GroupId'" and "Invalid Column Name 'UserId'". I imagine there is an extra ( or ) somewhere; please help me find it!

The outer query:

```
SELECT     coalesce(t1.PreferenceId,up.preferenceId) 
        as preferenceId, CASE t1.override WHEN 1 THEN COALESCE 
        (up.properties, t1.properties) 
        When 0 then t1.properties   
        ELSE up.properties END AS Properties
    FROM         
        (SELECT     u.UserId, u.GroupId, u.username,
            gp.PreferenceId, gp.Properties, gp.Override
        FROM          dbo.UserTable u 
        Inner JOIN
            dbo.GroupPreferences gp ON gp.GroupID = u.GroupId
        WHERE      (u.UserName = 'myUserId')) t1 
    full OUTER JOIN
        (select preferenceId, properties from UserPreferences u
        inner join userTable t on u.userId = t.userId and u.GroupId = 
        t.GroupId where userName = 'myUserId') up 
    ON t1.GroupId = up.GroupID AND t1.UserId = up.UserId
        AND t1.PreferenceId = up.PreferenceId
```

Comment: As a friendly sugguestion, you might want to clean up your SQL formatting a bit. More or less, treat it like you're writing C# or java. Just think of the '(' as '{' and indent properly. The cleaner you can get your queries, the easier it will be to find the mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing columns `GroupId` and `UserId` from the inline view aliased `up`, but it does not include those columns in its select list.

Change the 14th line to include those columns:

```
(select t.GroupId, t.userId, preferenceId, properties from UserPreferences u
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
(select preferenceId, properties from UserPreferences u
        inner join userTable t on u.userId = t.userId and u.GroupId = 
        t.GroupId where userName = 'myUserId') up
```

doesn't have up.GroupID or  up.UserId

```
ON t1.GroupId = up.GroupID AND t1.UserId = up.UserId
```